# Basic trigonometry - Find length of side when knowing one side length and the opposite angle

Tags: trigonometry

I have this basic trigonometry question of finding the length of "x" in the triangle [Finding X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyZVH.png). I know one side of the triangle and the opposite angle, so I figured it should be a simple case of just filling in the equations of cosine.
I've tried looking at other solutions of similar problems, but I can't wrap my head around how to apply their approach to my problem.

Sorry if this is way too basic, I notice it's been too long since I've used trig..

Comment: Use the tangent (or cotangent) instead of the cosine, since you aren't given the hypotenuse.

Comment: Actually, according to your figure, you know two angles: the $6$-degree angle and the right angle. That is what makes this problem solvable.

Comment: This may be helpful in applying trigonometry to right triangles: https://www.intmath.com/trigonometric-functions/2-sin-cos-tan-csc-sec-cot.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tan \theta =\dfrac{\text{side opposite }\theta}{\text{side adjacent }\theta}$$

Here the $\text{side opposite }\theta$ to the angle of $6^{\circ}$ is $x$ and $\text{side adjacent }\theta$ is $3$.

$$\tan 6^{\circ}=\dfrac{x}{3}\implies x=3\tan6^{\circ}$$

You can leave it like that as $6^{\circ}$ is not a special angle, if however, you can use a calculator, simply feed in the expression to get $x \approx 0.315312705798$ and you're done.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi30.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference @ClaudeLeibovici I meant _special angle_ in the sense those that're usually remembered by most people like $\{0, 30, 45, 60, 90\}$ for the acute angle case. A value like $\tan 6^{\circ}$ is best to be left computed than remembered.

Comment: For sure, I agree ! But, it is nice to know that we have an exact result. Replace the $3$ meters by $12345678987654321$ km and we can produce the exact result say within an error of $10^{-10}$ microns ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Sure that is true @ClaudeLeibovici. Cheers

Comment: Sure @ClaudeLeibovici "Numerical Efficiency is your main concern" :)

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Use tangent: $\tan 6°=\frac{x}{3} \rightarrow x=3\tan 6° \approx 0.32$